# javascript good way to create or design Singleton class

Tags: javascript, node.js, design-patterns

I think in javascript it could create Singleton class like below

```
test.js
class Container {
    constructor() {
      this.map = new Map;
    }

    set(key, value) {
      this.map.set(key, value);
    }

    get(key) {
      return this.map.get(key);
    }
  }
module.exports.Container = new Container();
```

so that 
I could use that other files like  in index.js

```
import container from './test'
```

However  the constructor of Container need some other parameters so that it could do better.  And the Container also need to be Singleton class  ,
because it is a common class . And i do not know how to create it?

```
constructor(servie) {
      this.map = new Map;
      this.servie = servie;
    }
```

by the way  the service variable is created when application starts

Comment: How do you imagine using this? Do you call `container('some value')` and get an object, and then later call `container('some other value')` and get the same singleton?

Comment: @MarkMeyer
I want to initialize the Container class when application starts.
And module.Then exports Container class as Singleton class which could work for other module. And I do not know how to do

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I've realised my naming is slightly confusing, as I've used Container to represent the IoC container, and then realised you've used that name to represent your Singleton.

Providing you are able to instantiate your singleton at a central point of code (entry point file for example, while setting up server). You can achieve a Singleton in a number of ways. For example:

```
let instance = null;
class Singleton {
  constructor(arg1, arg2) {
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.arg2 = arg2;
  }
}

module.exports = (...args) => {
  return instance || (instance = new Singleton(...args));
}
```

You could do this any multitude of ways e.g. with static functions instead of the anonymous function. However, with all of these I think it becomes slightly confused as to whether you're init'ing the instance or just trying to retrieve it.

IoC container patterns (often used in C# projects) are a little cleaner in my opinion. Where you might have a single container class that keeps track of your singletons and provides separate access and initiation functions.

```
class Container {
  constructor() {
    this.instances = {};
  }

  add(name, instance) {
    this.instances[name] = instance; // depends if you want overwrite or not
  }

  get(name) {
    if (!this.instances[name]) {
      throw new Error('some appropriate error messaging for your app');
    }
    return this.instances[name];
  }

  remove(name) {
    delete this.instances[name];
  }
}

module.exports = new Container(); // this has to be a no-param constructor
```

Then in your app init code, you initialise the singletons and register them with your container:

```
const Container = require('<path_to_Container>');
const Singleton = require('<path_to_Singleton>');
...
Container.add('mySingleton', new Singleton(arg1, arg2));
```

and access it at any time with:

```
Container.get('mySingleton');
```

Couple notes:

- You could use Singleton.name instead of a string name ('mySingleton' in the example)
- This is just a personal preference. But I like it because it feels more declarative, you register (add) an instance to the container at app start-up and don't blur the lines between initialisation and usage. And it means that if you add more of these singletons going forward, you have a single pattern for it already in place.